# how do I change the color in 'justify-content: space-between;' CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I add a color to *space-between* so that '`background-color:lightblue;`' remains the same rather then leaving a huge blank in my menu bar after the LINK.

[image: NO BLANK_SPACES]

```css
#main {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
}
#main div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">LINK</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">LINK</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">LINK</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">LINK</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `width` on `#main div`'s?

Comment: @NenadVracar the width only makes it a fixed size but I want to remove the spaces within the '<div id="main">'

Comment: Just add the same bg to the main div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a plain-color and a simple way, `box-shadow` could help:

```css
#main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
  overflow:hidden;
}
#main div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;box-shadow:-40px 0 lightblue, 40px 0 lightblue">LINK</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;box-shadow:-40px 0 lightblue, 40px 0 lightblue">LINK</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;box-shadow:-40px 0 lightblue, 40px 0 lightblue">LINK</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;box-shadow:-40px 0 lightblue, 40px 0 lightblue">LINK</div>
</div>
```